# Merging rows to one row with inner join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, inner-join

I have a `products` table in SQL Server like this:

```
ID      ItemCode        ProductName
------  ------------    -----------------
1       8680972060039   test product
2       123457          coffee
3       123458          tea
```

and I have a `price` table for these products like this:

```
PriceListLineID                         ItemCode        Price       PriceGroupCode  LastUpdatedDate
------------------------------------    --------------  ---------   --------------  ------------------------
D7B4F7A5-3CEF-4FFB-B90A-A81700D6CCE8    8680972060039   79,00       B2C             2017-10-25 15:44:30.640
3456748E-FA54-4683-83E7-A81700D6CC40    8680972060039   75,00       B2B             2017-10-25 15:44:30.117
CF03A676-4276-432B-BA7B-A76A0128D9B6    8680972060039   124,00      B2C             2017-05-05 20:47:05.197
5257C168-365A-475E-B2FD-A76A0128D8EF    8680972060039   118,00      B2B             2017-05-05 20:47:04.630
```

I want to show last updated both b2c and b2b prices near with product details like

```
ItemCode    ProductName         B2BPrice    B2CPrice
------------    -------------   ---------   -----------
8680972060039   test product    79,00       75,00
```

I use one inner join to get prices but i can not get second price with it how can i do it ?

This is the SQL code I use:

```
select 
    Products.ItemCode, Products.ProductName, Prices.Price 
from 
    Products WITH(NOLOCK)
inner join
    Prices with(nolock) on Prices.ItemCode = Products.ItemCode 
                        and Prices.PriceGroupCode = 'B2B'  
                        and Prices.Price is not null
order by
    Prices.LastUpdated desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the query below, I think `top 1` trick will help:

```
select Products.ItemCode, Products.ProductName,
       B2BPrice = (Select top 1 p.Price from Prices p where p.ItemCode = Products.ItemCode and p.PriceGroupCode='B2B' order by LastUpdatedDate desc),
       B2CPrice = (Select top 1 p.Price from Prices p where p.ItemCode = Products.ItemCode and p.PriceGroupCode='B2C' order by LastUpdatedDate desc)
from Products WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Prices with(nolock) on Prices.ItemCode = Products.ItemCode
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `outer apply`:

```
select p.*, pr_b2b.price as b2b_price, pr.b2c.price as b2c_price
from products p outer apply
     (select top (1) pr.*
      from prices pr
      where pr.ItemCode = pr.ItemCode and pr.PriceGroupCode = 'B2B'
      order by pr.LastUpdatedDate desc
     ) pr_b2b outer apply
     (select top (1) pr.*
      from prices pr
      where pr.ItemCode = pr.ItemCode and pr.PriceGroupCode = 'B2C'
      order by pr.LastUpdatedDate desc
     ) pr_b2c;
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `prices(ItemCode, PriceGroupCode, LastUpdatedDate)`.

Comment: @hakansen . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer for an inferior answer?  You will note that this answer does not have an extra `JOIN` for the outer select, which should make it both more performance and more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Price column to get B2BPrice and B2CPrice, then why you don't take advantage of `LEAD` and `LAG` functions instead?

LEAD function will give you the next value, while LAG will get you the previous one.

Here is an example :

```
SELECT TOP 1
    prod.ItemCode, 
    prod.ProductName, 
    price.Price AS B2BPrice,
    LEAD(price.Price) OVER(PARTITION BY prod.ItemCode ORDER BY prod.ItemCode) AS B2CPrice
FROM 
    Products prod
LEFT JOIN Prices price ON price.ItemCode = prod.ItemCode
WHERE 
    PriceGroupCode = 'B2B'
OR PriceGroupCode = 'B2C' 
ORDER BY
    LastUpdatedDate DESC
```

Since you can order the table by LastUpdatedDate in descending order, this will put the last two prices at the top of the results, so instead of using `TOP 2` and do extra work, you simply divide the price column into two columns, one will have the current value (B2BPrice) and second one will get the next value (B2CPrice). After that you can just select the TOP 1 row which will be your result.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to do that via `subquery`

```
select ItemCode, roductName,
      (select top 1 Price 
       from Prices 
       where ItemCode = p.ItemCode and 
             PriceGroupCode = 'B2B' 
       order by LastUpdatedDate desc) as B2BPrice,
      (select top 1 Price 
       from Prices 
       where ItemCode = p.ItemCode and 
             PriceGroupCode = 'B2C' 
       order by LastUpdatedDate desc) as B2CPrice,
from products p
where ItemCode = 8680972060039;
```

In other way, you could also use `row_number()` function

```
select p.ItemCode, p.ProductName, 
       max(case when pr.PriceGroupCode = 'B2B' then pr.price end) B2BPrice,
       max(case when pr.PriceGroupCode = 'B2C' then pr.price end) B2CPrice   
from (select *, 
             row_number() over(partition by ItemCode, PriceGroupCode 
                                      order by LastUpdatedDate desc) Seq
     from Prices 
     where PriceGroupCode  in ('B2B', 'B2C')) pr 
inner join products p on p.ItemCode = pr.ItemCode
where pr.Seq = 1 and 
      p.ItemCode = 8680972060039 
group by p.ItemCode, p.ProductName;
```